# Why does this C code sample use a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

The following code sample demonstrates the similarities between pointers and arrays. In the second method, the author declares cur_name as a pointer to a pointer. My question is, why is this necessary? Why does he declare a new pointer instead of just using the original pointer, names? I should note, the code compiles and runs fine when I get rid of cur_name and use names, so is it a matter of style rather than function? Any explanation would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // create two arrays we care about
    int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
    char *names[] = {"Alan", "Frank", "Mary", "John", "Lisa"};

    // safely get the size of ages
    int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;

    // first way using indexing
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s has %d years alive.\n",
                names[i], ages[i]);
    }

    printf("---\n");

    // setup the pointers to the start of the arrays
    int *cur_age = ages;
    char **cur_name = names;

    // second way using pointers
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s is %d years old.\n",
                *(cur_name+i), *(cur_age+i));
    }

    printf("---\n");

    // third way, pointers are just arrays
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s is %d years old again.\n",
                cur_name[i], cur_age[i]);
    }

    printf("---\n");

    // fourth way with pointers in a stupid complex way
    for(cur_name = names, cur_age = ages;
            (cur_age - ages) < count;
            cur_name++, cur_age++)
    {
        printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n",
                *cur_name, *cur_age);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code contains the comment `// third way, pointers are just arrays`; that is inaccurate — **pointers are _not_ arrays**.  However, the two _are_ closely related.  Consider the values of `sizeof(cur_name)` and `sizeof(names)`; these values are quite different, so clearly pointers are not arrays.  Note that `sizeof(argv)` is the same as `sizeof(cur_names)`; that's because another valid way of writing an array parameter like `char *argv[]` is `char **argv`. So, arrays passed as arguments are pointers (which is where the confusion comes from), but local or global arrays are not `just pointers'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code uses a pointer to a pointer to represent a pointer into an array of C strings. Namely, `cur_name` is a pointer into the array of C strings called `names`. Since a string in C is itself represented by a pointer to `char`, a pointer into the array of such pointers becomes a pointer to a pointer.

> Why does he declare a new pointer instead of just using the original pointer, `names`?

Because `names` is not a pointer, it is an array of pointers (see the square brackets after the declaration? That is what makes `names` an array. The single asterisk in front is related to the type of the array element, which is a `char*` in this program).

Making an array adds a level of indirection: to point into an array of `int`s you need `int*`, but to point into an array of `int*` you need an `int**` pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. A point of clarification, though. If `names` is not a pointer, then why does `*(names + i)` return the same value as `*(cur_name + i)` in the 3rd method?

Comment: @intelli78 That is a great question! The reason for it is that all the rules of pointer arithmetics apply to arrays as well. The name of the array in such expressions is treated in the same way in which a pointer to the initial element of the array would be treated. In other words, if you were to make `char **names2 = names`, pointer arithmetic expressions on it would behave the same was as the same expressions on `names`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of type T as below

```
T a[N];
```

then  if you want to define a pointer to its first element you have to write

```
T *p = a;
```

Now substitute T for the type of elements of array `names` defined as

```
char *names[] = {"Alan", "Frank", "Mary", "John", "Lisa"};
```

You will get

```
typedef char * T;
T names[] = {"Alan", "Frank", "Mary", "John", "Lisa"};
```

so the pointer to the first element of the array will look like

```
T *cur_name = names;
```

If you now will make the reverse substitution you will get

```
char * *cur_name = names;
^^^^^^
  T
```

Answer (score 0):

The author does increment them in the fourth method, so he needs the temporaries for that, but you are correct about it not being necessary in the second method. Perhaps (s)he is using the assignment to show their equivalence?

I think the examples would be clearer if each method was implemented in its own function.